# Having trouble implementing cp -u in shell script

Tags: linux, bash

For a school project, I have a shell script that is supposed to copy the files in two directories (without looking at subdirectories) into a third directory. I'm testing out the -u command so that if two files have the same name, only the newer one will get copied over (that's also a spec). My shell script looks like this (excluding #! and error checking):

```
cd $1 #first directory

for file in `ls`; do
    if [ -f $file ]; then
        cp "$file" ../$3 # $3 is the third directory
    fi
done

cd ../$2

for file in `ls`; do
    if [ -f $file ]; then
        cp -u "$file" ../$3
    fi
done
```

My current shell script will copy files that don't exist in directory 3 already, and it won't overwrite a newer file with an older file with the same name. However, my shell script doesn't overwrite an older file with a newer file of the same name in directory 3. I don't think there's anything wrong with the -u command. Can you help find the bug in my code? Thanks!

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: That being said when do you expect `[ -f $file ]` to fail? You have just gotten that name from `ls` why would the file not exist at this point? Which directory has the newer file that should replace the older file but doesn't? `$1` or `$2`? Are you supposed to compare files in `$3` against the input directories or just against each other?

Comment: When you do ls it lists all the contents inside the current directory including directories. Thus I only want to execute the cp statement if file is actually a file and not a directory.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, filtering for files with `-f` is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `-u` option in the first loop:

```
cp "$file" ../$3 # $3 is the third directory
```

should instead  read:

`cp`**`-u`**`"$file" ../$3 # $3 is the third directory`

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: huh, reread question -- I'm wrong, sorry. Thus he may have problems if `$3` already has file which is older then same file in `$1` but newer then one in `$2`

Comment: I hope I'm right. Getting that `-u` to come out in teletype and bold was painful.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev if a file in $3 is older than in $1, but newer than the one in $2, then the file in $1 will also be newer than in $2, so not a problem there (order of creation would have been $2 $3 $1, making $1 the newest). file from $1 will update the one in $3 and the file in $2 will not modify it.

Comment: What if you run the program twice?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the second run would change nothing, assuming no files were modified/added between runs.